# View returns null list to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning `asp.net` and I am doing a project and I ran into this problem and I don't know how to fix it. When I go to the `[HttpPost]` the subjects list's count is 0. How can I make the list with the same information as in the `[HttpGet]` and only the `TeacherId` changed?

Controller:

```
namespace Better_Shkolo.Controllers
{
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var teacher = teacherService.GetTeacher(id);
            var grade = gradeService.GetGradeByTeacherId(teacher.Id);
            var subjects = subjectService.GetSubjectsByTeacherId(teacher.Id);

            if (grade == null && subjects == null)
            {
                var result = teacherService.DeleteTeacher(id);

                if (!result)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            var model = new GradeDeleteModel()
            {
                GradeName = grade.GradeName,
                GradeSpecialty = grade.GradeSpecialty,
                SchoolId = grade.SchoolId,
                Teachers = teacherService.GetAllTeacherInSchool(teacher.SchoolId).Where(x => x.Id != teacher.Id).ToList(),
                Subjects = subjects,
                OldTeacherId = teacher.Id,
            };

            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(GradeDeleteModel model)
        {
            var subjects = model.Subjects;

            foreach (var item in subjects)
            {
                var subject = context.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
                subject.TeacherId = item.TeacherId;
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I switched to `for()` instead of `foreach()` and used `@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Subjects[i].Name)` but it still doesn't work.

View:

```
@using Better_Shkolo.Models.Grade;
@model GradeDeleteModel

<h3 class="text-center">@ViewData["Title"]</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                ...
                @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Subjects.Count; i++)
                {
                    <p class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Subjects[i].Name);
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Subjects[i].Name)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="@Model.Subjects[i].TeacherId"></label>
                            <select asp-for="@Model.Subjects[i].TeacherId" class="form-control">
                                @foreach (var teacher in Model.Teachers.Where(x => x.Id != Model.OldTeacherId))
                                {
                                    <option value="@teacher.Id">@teacher.FirstName @teacher.LastName - @teacher.Email</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                }

                ...
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Subjects" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before putting `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Subjects" />` the list was null now it's not null but with count 0.

Comment: Could you please explain what are your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not how asp.net mvc works. A GET request is separate from a POST request. I.e. there's no data communicated from the get to the post, apart from what you put in the message body.
I.e. if you want`subjects` to be communicated to the post, you would have to put *all* that data in the form body. It's not like the model is forwarded to the client and send back with the response.

Usually you would just call the database query (`var subjects = subjectService.GetSubjectsByTeacherId(teacher.Id);`) again in the POST method. Then apply the changes from the response and save those.

If the query is costly, you could add a caching service. Note: the controller itself has a lifetime coupled to the request, so don't use that for caching.